# strange nil object result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module:

```
module Voteable
  def has_up_vote_of user
    return ! self.votes.select{|v| v.user.id == user.id && v.value == 1}.empty?
  end
  def has_down_vote_of user
    return ! self.votes.select{|v| v.user.id == user.id && v.value == -1}.empty?
  end
end
```

Which is mixed into a model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Voteable
end
```

In a controller code, there is a check:

```
has_up_vote = @voteable.has_up_vote_of @user
has_down_vote = @voteable.has_down_vote_of @user
```

@voteable and @user are existing model items, found in a DB.

Suppose, voteable item has up-vote of user. After executing the code, has_up_vote will be equal to true, and **has_down_vote will be nil**.

Why nil, instead of false ?

I have used several variations of methods, but the problem is the same. Even this gives me the same effect:

```
def has_up_vote_of user
  has = self.votes.select{|v| v.user.id == user.id && v.value == 1}.empty?
  return !has.nil? && has
end
```

Posssible, i'm misunderstanding something, but this behavior is strange

**Update**

I've noticed very strange behaviour.

When i change methods to trivial:

```
def has_up_vote_of user
  return false
end
def has_down_vote_of user
  return false
end
```

They both returns nil, when i debug the app.
But, from console, they returns false.

It's more stange, because i cannot do anything with these results. These code is not working:

```
has_up_vote = false if has_up_vote.nil?
has_down_vote = false if has_down_vote.nil?
```

Comment: What do you get for `self.votes.map { |v| [v.user.id, v.value] }`?

Comment: I get the same result (has_down_vote is nil)

Comment: I'm asking you to `puts` that statement, not substitute it for the `select`.

Comment: Thats odd, i'm trying to replicate this with:

`ruby-1.8.7-p302 > def test2; return ! [User.last, User.first].select {|u| u.id == 10000 && 1 == -1 }.empty?; end
 => nil 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > test2
 => false`

This should be about the same and this does give me back false and never nil.

Do you try these tests in console?
What do you get if you paste that line in console: 
`(! Comment.last.votes.select{|v| v.user.id == user.id && v.value == -1}.empty?)`

Comment: @John Feminella, it returns an array of pairs [v.user_id, v.value]

Comment: @Danny Hiemstra, I'm debugging the sources from Aptana RadRails 2.0.4.1268158942. From console, i get true and false, without nil's.

Comment: As a first though - something is wrong in Aptana's debugger. BUT, the logic of the app goes wrong way. All if's, relies on there methods, are always evaluates to false.

Comment: My environment is - ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the debugging environment you're running in is interfering with the actual value of `has_down_votes`. The `select` method should never return `nil` as defined.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of !{}.empty? you could use {}.present?

Its more readable and the output will always be true/false only

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't get to the root cause of your strange problem, but it should give you the results you want.  Instead of

```
return ! self.votes.select{|v| v.user.id == user.id && v.value == -1}.empty?
```

try

```
return !!self.votes.select{|v| v.user.id == user.id && v.value == -1}.any?
```

The double exclamation point is intentional -- it will cause nil to become false.  (!arr.empty? is equivalent to arr.any? which is equivalent to !!arr.any? -- except the last one converts the nil to false)